# Don't let users buy more than one product of the same type in commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

how can I prevent users from buying more than one product of same product type in Drupal commerce?
I need a solution using rules module.

be careful please!!!as I need to limit users on product type (not products) my question is not duplication of any others

Comment: [Restrict Qty](https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/673/restrict-qty), [How to limit maximum quantity to 1 for one given product type ?](https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/8066/how-limit-maximum-quantity-1-one-given-product-type), [limit order quantity in drupal commerce](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154035/limit-order-quantity-in-drupal-commerce), [Line Item Quantities in Drupal Commerce.mov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkplhIhCSu8) etc.

Comment: none of theme was what I need